# continuous integration with aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

Repo hosted on awscommit.  I'm looking at setting up a continuous integration solution in AWS. I don't have much knowledge on AWS code deploy and aws pipeline. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: You could start by having a look at the Developers Tools services that AWS provides. They are all very well documented. Your question is actually too broad to be answered in a few lines.

Comment: There are numerous training videos on the Amazon 'Code' products. Watch a couple of YouTube videos such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4NSyUbAEkw or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lrrgd0Kemhw

Comment: Do you want to do set up your pipelines through the AWS Console (UI) or using infrastructure as code?

Comment: @blairnangle I want to set up using pipeline.

Comment: @user3906723 [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html) AWS tutorial explains how to create a pipeline using CodeCommit, CodePipeline and CodeDeploy.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Open code pipeline in aws developer console

```
     Make pipeline with source repo as of code commit and if any need connect         
     code build and at the end you can add code deploy
```

On the change in code commit and on the commit code pipeline will fetch code from code commit and build in code build as per the spec of the code build yaml file.

With code deploy simple add the end point Elastic bean stalk or ec2 or s3 anything you can add

Code pipeline : Work to connect end and transfer code form one end to another end

Code Build : Build and code and as output give and provide artifacts

Code deploy : Deploy final code to aws services

OR :

From using code pipeline you can direct send code artifacts to elastic beanstalks and also

Flow will be like : Code pipeline >>> Elastic beanstalk or anything  (s3)

OR :

From using code pipeline to code build you can send artifaces direct to elastic beanstalk

Flow will be like : Code pipeline >>> Code Build >>> Elastic beanstalk or anything